# How to return data matching certain parts of the JOIN criteria, almost like FULL OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's what I'm trying to figure out.  Suppose I have two datasets that I'm trying to compare by joining them together and put them side by side and see differences:

```
Table1
Name       Description       Style          Cost
Chair-1    Simple Chair      Contemporary   $100

Table2
Name       Description       Style          Cost
Chair-1    Simple Chair      Modern         $150
```

I would write some SQL like this:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Description, T1.Style, T1.Cost
T2.Name, T2.Description, T2.Style, T2.Cost
FROM Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.Name = T2.Name
AND T1.Description = T2.Description
AND T1.Style = T2.Style
--WHERE T1.Cost <> T2.Cost
```

However, the result set would give me 2 records with NULLs in T2 fields for the T1 record and NULLs in the T1 fields for the T2 record because they don't match exactly.

My question is: Is there any way to join these two datasets together to get them side by side if they match on SOME of the fields but not ALL?  I attempted to do this with the FULL OUTER JOIN but they still have to match on all the fields in the JOIN criteria.

For example, since the two records above have the same Name and Description but different Style, I'd want them to be joined together because they matched 2 out of 3 conditions.

I'd be running this on SQL Server 2016.

EDIT:  I think this might be a use case for OUTER APPLY but I'm not entirely sure.  I re-wrote my code to look like this (the example is all pseudo-code):

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Description, T1.Style, T1.Cost
T2.Name, T2.Description, T2.Style, T2.Cost
FROM Table1 T1
OUTER APPLY 
(
SELECT T2.Name, T2.Description, T2.Style, T2.Cost
FROM Table2 T2
WHERE T1.Name = T2.Name
AND T1.Description = T2.Description
AND T1.Style = T2.Style
--AND T1.Cost <> T2.Cost --This is what I'm looking for ultimately
) T2
```

Do I understand it right that OUTER APPLY will return records with the most matching criteria?

Comment: You can use `OR` instead of `AND` in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Did you try using what I have posted in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a join using `OR`.

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Description, T1.Style, T1.Cost
       T2.Name, T2.Description, T2.Style, T2.Cost
FROM Table1 T1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     Table2 T2
     ON T1.Name = T2.Name OR
        T1.Description = T2.Description OR
        T1.Style = T2.Style
```

This will give you results if any 1 of the 3 columns matches. To can use a combination of `AND` and `OR` to get it to match 2 of the 3 columns.

Example:

```
(T1.Name = T2.Name AND T1.Description = T2.Description)
OR (T1.Description = T2.Description AND T1.Style = T2.Style)
OR (T1.Name = T2.Name AND T1.Style = T2.Style)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tried this and created multiple join conditions with ORs and my dataset nearly doubled because the records met multiple conditions.  Not sure how to filter that down to just those that meet on the record with the closest match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can move the `where` condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Description, T1.Style, T1.Cost
       T2.Name, T2.Description, T2.Style, T2.Cost
FROM Table1 T1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     Table2 T2
     ON T1.Name = T2.Name AND
        T1.Description = T2.Description AND
        T1.Style = T2.Style AND
        T1.Cost <> T2.Cost
```

`FULL OUTER JOIN`s are tricky where filtering is involved.  If you don't want rows where the costs match, then add:

```
WHERE T1.Cost IS NOT NULL AND t2.Cost IS NOT NULL
```

But, that is equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Description, T1.Style, T1.Cost
       T2.Name, T2.Description, T2.Style, T2.Cost
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN
     Table2 T2
     ON T1.Name = T2.Name AND
        T1.Description = T2.Description AND
        T1.Style = T2.Style AND
        T1.Cost <> T2.Cost;
```

This is likely what you really want.

Comment: This isn't really what he's after, I don't think.   Notice in the sample data the Style values do not match.

Comment: This is how I have been doing the comparisons but I'm getting a lot of NULLs on both sides because not every part of the JOIN is matched.  Let me update my post with something I found.

Comment: @benchwrmr22 . . . The `inner join` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

`OUTER APPLY` will return all records from both tables, including those without matches. The most common reason you'd need to use APPLY instead of a JOIN is when you're "applying" a table value function to an existing table. In other words, you're doing a JOIN, but you're joining TableA with a table that is the result of a query (kinda like a view) rather than another existing table. It sounds like in this case, you'd be better off with a `JOIN`. However, in a few cases `OUTER APPLY` can be faster - another potential reason for using it. I'm no expert on optimizing runtime though so you'd have to look at the execution plan.

clinomaniac's answer is good, but the only (potential) issue is that you might run into a scenario where you get more rows than you wanted. In other words, I believe that using those `OR` operators will produce duplicate rows because each row will match with multiple rows.

I think you're best option might be to use a `CASE WHEN` statement just to be safe.

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Description, T1.Style, T1.Cost
       T2.Name, T2.Description, T2.Style, T2.Cost
FROM Table1 T1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     Table2 T2
     ON case when T1.Name = T2.Name then T1.Name
             when T1.Description = T2.Description then T1.Description
             else T1.Style
             end
             =
        case when T1.Name = T2.Name then T2.Name
             when T1.Description = T2.Description then T2.Description
             else T2.Style
             end
```